# Equation Numbers Appearing Below Equations

Tags: equations, numbering

I am new to LaTex, but I am trying to make it so that my equation numbers are aligned with my equations. However, what keeps happening (and I can't explain why) is my equation numbers start appearing below my equations at about the 10th equation. The first 9 equations seem to be okay though, but I haven't really changed anything in regards to my formatting so I am not able to explain what the problem is. Additionally, I am not sure how you would go about getting some extra space before the equation numbers because it appears to be fairly cluttered.

Like I said, I am fairly new to LaTex so my code is probably gross, but if somebody has any recommendations I would be happy to hear them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ stmaryrd }
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \min_{L_{t}} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{t=1}^T(a + b L_{t}^{ij}) G_{t,PostDispersal}^{ij} \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad & j_{t,k} = sj_{t-1,k-1}  & k=2,...,kmax; \quad \forall i,j,t \\
    \quad & j_{t,1} = dJ_{t-1} + \tilde{d}\mathcal{G}_{t-1} & \forall i,j,t  \\
    \quad & J_{t} = \sum_{k=1}^{kmax} j_{t,k}  & \forall i,j,t \\
    \quad & S_{t} = \max\left\{S_{t-1} + sj_{t-1,kmax} - G_{t-1,NewGrowth}, 0\right\} & \forall i,j,t \\
    \quad & R_{t} = G_{t-1,PostTreatment} & t=1, ... ,T; \quad \forall i,j \\
    \quad & \mathcal{G}_{t} =  \mathcal(1-\tilde{d})\mathcal{G}_{t-1} + R_{t} & \forall i,j,t \\
    \quad & G_{t,B4Dispersal} = G_{t-1,PostTreatment} & \forall i,j,t \\
    \quad & D_{t}^{(i,j)_n \shortrightarrow(i,j)} = \lambda\sum_{(o,p) \in N}G_{t,B4Dispersal} & \forall i,j,t \\    
    \quad & D_{t}^{(i,j)\shortrightarrow(i,j)} = \lambda\mathcal{N}G_{t,B4Dispersal} & \forall i,j,t \\
    \quad & G_{t,PostDispersal} = \max\left\{G_{t,B4Dispersal}+D_{t}^{(i,j)_n\shortrightarrow(i,j)} -D_{t}^{(i,j)\shortrightarrow(i,j)}, 0\right\} & \forall i,j,t & \tag{11}\\
    \quad & G_{t,NewGrowth} = \frac{G_{t,PostDispersal}^{2}} {G_{t,PostDispersal}^{2} + a^2} S_{t}  & \forall i,j,t & \tag{12}\\
    \quad & G_{t,PostTreatment} = (1-L_{t})G_{t,NewGrowth} & \forall i,j,t & \tag{13}\\
    \quad & \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{t=1}^TbL_{t}^{ij} \le B & \forall i,j,t & \tag{14}
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
    S_{0},R_{0},\mathcal{G}_{0}, J_{0},G_{0,PostTreatment} \ge 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Edited to include that, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because equation  (11) is to long. You can solve the problem using `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` with  the last part of this equation. It took the opportunity to add some code simplification and a few improvements to the layout:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ stmaryrd }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{comment}

    \begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    \min_{L_{t}} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{t=1}^T(a + b L_{t}^{ij}) G_{t, \text{PostDispersal}}^{ij} \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad & j_{t,k} = sj_{t-1,k-1} & k=2,...,k_{\max}; \quad &\forall i,j,t \\
     & j_{t,1} = dJ_{t-1} + \tilde{d}\mathcal{G}_{t-1} & & \forall i,j,t \\
     & J_{t} = \sum_{k=1}^{\mathclap{k_{\max}}} j_{t,k} & & \forall i,j,t \\
     & S_{t} = \max\left\{S_{t-1} + sj_{t-1,k_{\max}} - G_{t-1,\text{NewGrowth}}, 0\right\} & & \forall i,j,t \\
     & R_{t} = G_{t-1,\text{PostTreatment}} & t=1, ... ,T; \quad & \forall i,j \\
     & \mathcal{G}_{t} = \mathcal(1-\tilde{d})\mathcal{G}_{t-1} + R_{t} & & \forall i,j,t \\
     & G_{t,\text{B4Dispersal}} = G_{t-1,\text{PostTreatment}} & & \forall i,j,t \\
     & D_{t}^{(i,j)_n \shortrightarrow(i,j)} = \lambda\sum_{\mathclap{(o,p) \in N}}G_{t,\text{B4Dispersal}} & & \forall i,j,t \\
     & D_{t}^{(i,j)\shortrightarrow(i,j)} = \lambda\mathcal{N}G_{t,\text{B4Dispersal}} & & \forall i,j,t \\
     & G_{t,\text{PostDispersal}} = \max\Bigl\{G_{t,\text{B4Dispersal}}+D_{t}^{(i,j)_n\shortrightarrow(i,j)} -\mathrlap{D_{t}^{(i,j)\shortrightarrow(i,j)}, 0\Bigr\}} && \forall i,j,t \\
     & G_{t,\text{NewGrowth}} = \frac{G_{t,\text{PostDispersal}}^{2}} {G_{t,\text{PostDispersal}}^{2} + a^2} S_{t} && \forall i,j,t \\
     & G_{t,\text{PostTreatment}} = (1-L_{t})G_{t,\text{NewGrowth}} & & \forall i,j,t \\
     & \smash[b]{\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{t=1}^T}bL_{t}^{ij} \le B & & \forall i,j,t
\end{alignat}
\useshortskip
\begin{align*}
    S_{0},R_{0},\mathcal{G}_{0}, J_{0},G_{0,\text{PostTreatment}} \ge 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is so much more presentable than what I had. Without putting too much of a burden on you, could you provide an explanation on a couple of the key areas that you changed so that things aligned properly? I'm fairly new to LaTex so i'm just trying to absorb what I can.

Comment: The main change is that you did not seem to perceive that a multiline equation with 2 alignment points (indeed two alignment columns) requires 3 ampersands: each column but the first requires a first `&` to mark the beginning of the new alignment column, and another to mark the alignment point inside that column. When the second `&` is missing, there's an alignment of the end of lines. Furthermore, I used `alignat` because it gives you control on the spacing of the alignment columns. I hope to be clear…

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing an alignment such that the for-all and k==.. conditions are to the right of the longest entry in the display, which makes them a long way from the terms they relate to and forces the lines to be too wide to take the equation number on the same line.

I dropped that alignment, and while there used `\mathrm` around multi-letter identifiers (never use math italic, it is designed for products of one-letter variables, not words) and allowed the lines to auto-number rather than using `\tag` beware using `\tag` with numbers, it will be very confusing if used on conjunction with automatically numbered constructs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ stmaryrd }
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \min_{L_{t}} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{t=1}^T(a + b L_{t}^{ij}) G_{t,\mathrm{PostDispersal}}^{ij} \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad  j_{t,k} &= sj_{t-1,k-1}  \qquad k=2,...,\mathrm{kmax}; \quad \forall i,j,t \\
      j_{t,1}  &= dJ_{t-1} + \tilde{d}\mathcal{G}_{t-1} \qquad\forall i,j,t  \\
      J_{t}  &= \sum_{k=1}^{kmax} j_{t,k}  \qquad\forall i,j,t \\
      S_{t}  &= \max\left\{S_{t-1} + sj_{t-1,\mathrm{kmax}} - G_{t-1,\mathrm{NewGrowth}}, 0\right\} \qquad\forall i,j,t \\
      R_{t}  &= G_{t-1,\mathrm{PostTreatment}} \qquad t=1, ... ,T; \quad \forall i,j \\
      \mathcal{G}_{t}  &=  \mathcal(1-\tilde{d})\mathcal{G}_{t-1} + R_{t} \qquad\forall i,j,t \\
      G_{t,\mathrm{B4Dispersal}}  &= G_{t-1,\mathrm{PostTreatment}} \qquad\forall i,j,t \\
      D_{t}^{(i,j)_n \shortrightarrow(i,j)}  &= \lambda\sum_{(o,p) \in N}G_{t,\mathrm{B4Dispersal}} \qquad\forall i,j,t \\    
      D_{t}^{(i,j)\shortrightarrow(i,j)}  &= \lambda\mathcal{N}G_{t,\mathrm{B4Dispersal}} \qquad\forall i,j,t \\
      G_{t,\mathrm{PostDispersal}}  &= \max\left\{G_{t,\mathrm{B4Dispersal}}+D_{t}^{(i,j)_n\shortrightarrow(i,j)} -D_{t}^{(i,j)\shortrightarrow(i,j)}, 0\right\} \qquad\forall i,j,t  \\
      G_{t,\mathrm{NewGrowth}}  &= \frac{G_{t,\mathrm{PostDispersal}}^{2}} {G_{t,\mathrm{PostDispersal}}^{2} + a^2} S_{t}  \qquad\forall i,j,t  \\
      G_{t,\mathrm{PostTreatment}}  &= (1-L_{t})G_{t,\mathrm{NewGrowth}} \qquad\forall i,j,t  \\
      \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J\sum_{t=1}^TbL_{t}^{ij} &\le B \qquad\forall i,j,t  \\
    S_{0},R_{0},\mathcal{G}_{0}, J_{0},G_{0,\mathrm{PostTreatment}} &\ge 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```